# Autocomplete/abbrev with calculation in Vim?

Tags: vim, temperature

I'm trying to script something like this in Vim, and it's raising a series of questions for me. I'm sure it's possible.

Whenever I insert a number followed by a capital F, like `88F`, I would like Vim to automatically convert that to `88°F (31°C)` -- that is, expanding the expression but also converting Fahrenheit to Celsius.

What's the best way to trigger that sort of inline expansion? And the best way to run the calculation?

Comment: I don't know about the inline expansion but there are several tips [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/VimTip73) about using vim as a calulator as well as calling `bc`to do more advance stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the refactoring of @kev’s answer that won’t force you to use `<C-v>F` and won’t touch any registers:

```
inoremap <expr> F ((col('.')>1 && getline('.')[col('.')-2]=~#'^\d$')?(printf(' °F (%d °C)', float2nr((matchstr(getline('.')[:(col('.')-2)], '\d\+$')-32)/1.8))):('F'))
```

Note that you must not use `imap` unless you know exactly why.

**Update:** 
Assuming that you use dot as a decimal separator, do not use scientific notation or common (for programming languages) truncations like `.1==0.1`, `10.==10.0`:

```
inoremap <expr> F ((col('.')>1 && getline('.')[col('.')-2]=~#'^\d$')?(printf(' °F (%.1g °C)', (str2float(matchstr(getline('.')[:(col('.')-2)], '\v\-?\d+(\.\d+)?$'))-32)/1.8)):('F'))
```

Comment: What would it take to make it work to a couple of decimal places?

Comment: Very nice. I kludged on another clause so it sticks to integers if you start with an integer. 

`inoremap <expr> F ((col('.')>1 && getline('.')[col('.')-2]=~#'^\d$')?((getline('.')[col('.')-4]!~'\.' && getline('.')[col('.')-3]!~'\.')?(printf('°F (%d°C)', float2nr((matchstr(getline('.')[:(col('.')-2)], '\d\+$')-32)/1.8))):(printf('°F (%.1g°C)', (str2float(matchstr(getline('.')[:(col('.')-2)], '\v\-?\d+(\.\d+)?$'))-32)/1.8))):('F'))`

Comment: @moonkey If you want to compare specific symbol with another one, use `is#`, not patterns (`getline('.')[col('.')-4] isnot# '.' && getline('.')[col('.')-3] isnot# '.'` or `stridx(getline('.')[(col('.')-4):(col('.')-3)], '.')==-1`.

Answer (score 1):

```
:imap F <ESC>ciw<C-R>=printf('%d°F (%d°C)', str2nr(@"), float2nr((str2nr(@")-32)/1.8))<CR>
```

It will expand `88F` to `88°F (31°C)` in `insert-mode`

**note:** if you want to type the character `F`, press <kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd><kbd>F</kbd>.

Comment: Amazing, thanks! For triggering I'm now looking into adding it as a snippet to Snipmate, but that seems difficult.